# Is there a way to get all the directories but not files in a directory in Python?

Tags: python, directory

This [link](http://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/file_handling/os_module.html) is using a custom method, but I just wanna see if there is a single method to do it in Python 2.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function to only list files, but it's easy enough to define in a couple of lines:

```
def listfiles(directory):
    return [f for f in os.listdir(directory) 
              if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, f))]
```

**EDIT**: fixed, thanks Stephan202

Comment: You mean os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, f)) instead of os.path.isfile(f)...

Comment: The question was to find only directories, not only files (which is an odd way around, I suppose)

Answer (score 3):

If *a_directory* is the directory you want to inspect, then:

`next(f1 for f in os.walk(a_directory))`

From the [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) reference:

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

Comment: +1: Though, you might want to break and not descend recursively into the subdirectories. Personally, I'd prefer calling os.listdir and os.isdir explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is.  Since directories are also files, you have to ask for all the files, then ask each one if it is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
def listdirs(path):
    ret = []
    for cur_name in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, cur_name)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            ret.append(cur_name)
    return ret

onlydirs = listdir("/tmp/")
print onlydirs
```

..or as a list-comprehension..

```
path = "/tmp/"
onlydirs = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, x))]
print onlydirs
```